# Select Row as a Column

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a simple table with the below values

[image]

I would like the output to be:

[image]

Comment: You can use pivot.

Comment: Thanks, can you send me the sql to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Filter1, Filter2
FROM
(SELECT Name, Attribute, Value
    FROM PivotEx) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(Value)
FOR Attribute IN (Filter1, Filter2)
) AS PivotTable
```